# command parameter not implemented. the server response was authenticate first (#5.5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I got an error msg like this when sending emails:

> command parameter not implemented. the server response was
>   authenticate first (#5.5.0)

But this error message is not coming in working time it comes only after 7pm.

Comment: but same code is fine in working hours and i never got this error message during working hours.

Answer (score 4):

Your server would be configured to allow mails only during working hours.
This is a common setting on a lot of smtp server(Usually done to prevent misuse of an SMTP server).

Contact your network admin to resolve it.