# Command parameter not implemented. The server response was: Authenticate first (#5.5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, smtp-auth

I am working on nopCommerce based on MVC ASP.NET my email was working fine before this last monday, now I noticed that it is not sending any email (registration, order confirmation, password recovery etc). when I checked the logs, I found this error Command `parameter not implemented. The server response was: Authenticate first (#5.5.0)`
Full error

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Command parameter not implemented. The
>   server response was: Authenticate first (#5.5.0) at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   Nop.Services.Messages.EmailSender.SendEmail(EmailAccount emailAccount,
>   String subject, String body, String fromAddress, String fromName,
>   String toAddress, String toName, String replyTo, String replyToName,
>   IEnumerable`1 bcc, IEnumerable`1 cc, String attachmentFilePath, String
>   attachmentFileName, Int32 attachedDownloadId) at
>   Nop.Services.Messages.QueuedMessagesSendTask.Execute()

Comment: The problem is with your SMTP server. Contact your network admin to resolve it.

Comment: But it was fine 3 days ago

Comment: But the error which you get say its problem with SMTP server.

Comment: Isn't there any possible way to authenticate from my code?

Comment: The problem is pretty self-explanatory: "*Authenitcate first*". You will need to add authentication into the code where you set credentials for sending email (sometimes in `Web.config`, sometimes in code - not sure without seeing your code). A quick search engine search will throw up plenty of tutorials on how to use authentication in .NET. It's possible the SMTP admin probably realised they had an open relay and a bot/person/system was *probably* using this to exploit it and send spam or something, hence why it was changed - just a possibility. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your SMTP server. Contact your network admin to resolve it.

> Isn't there any possible way to authenticate from my code?

Nope you know only that your server response (#5.5.0) when you try send mail. It's mean you not allow to send mail by this server which you use. If it worked, ask admin what is going now with server.

[Here is problem like your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245356/command-parameter-not-implemented-the-server-response-was-authenticate-first)